# Pycharm warning: must implement all abstract methods

Tags: python, inheritance, warnings, pycharm

**Code**

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):
    def a(self):
        return 7

class C(B):
    pass
```

**Why does Pycharm complain?**

> Problem synopsis      Class C must implement all abstract methods

Comment: Which version of pycharm ?

Comment: I have version 5.0.1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a reported bug - you can vote for it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16132

Answer (score 19):

I find that warning relevant, so I would not disable it globally. You can instrument a false positive (erroneous warning) with `# noqa` and it should silence the PyCharm warning:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):  # noqa
   pass
```

note: I have not found a narrower warning/error code.

Comment: Didn't know this feature existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

We can disable this warning as follows:

- Goto Preferences/Settings > Editor > Inspections
- Search for **Class must implement all abstract methods**
- uncheck it, then click apply

Answer (score 4):

As expected, python itself recognises that instances of Class C are valid. So I suspected an bug in PyCharm.

Googling for PyCharm Bug Tracker got me to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Sure enough a ticket has been raised.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16132

No fix yet

Comment: Not fixed as of timestamp of this comment...2+ years later. Super difficult to do code reviews.

Comment: Still appears to be broken in Pycharm 2019.3 CE.

Comment: Still appears to be broken in Pycharm 2020.2 Professional Edition